# filtrar por current date

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

*como le agrego una condicional a esta funcion para que solo me imprima los eventos futuros al currentdate que me ya me dieron en otra pagina de data.js?*

```
function cargarTarjetas(eventsArray, container) {
    let cardsData = ''
    for (const event of eventsArray) {
        cardsData += `<div class="card">
        <img src="${event.image}" class="card-img-top" alt="${event.name}">
            <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
                <div class="row">
                    <h5 class="card-title">${event.name}</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="row flex-grow-1">
                    <div class="col">
                        <p class="card-text">${event.description}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex flex-nowrap align-content-center align-items-center">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1">
                        Price: $ ${event.price}
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex flex-grow-0">
                        <a href="./details.html" class="btn btn-primary">Details</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>`
    }
    container.innerHTML = cardsData}
```

*ese es el índex y la data es esta en otra pagina js todo especificado*

```
    "currentDate": "2022-01-01",
    "events": [
      {
        _id: 1,
        "image":"https://i.postimg.cc/Fs03hQDt/Collectivities-Party.jpg",
        "name":"Collectivities Party",
        "date":"2021-12-12",
        "description":"Enjoy your favourite dishes, from different countries, in a unique event for the whole family.",
        "category":"Food Fair",
        "place":"Room A",
        "capacity":45000,
        "assistance":42756,
        "price":5
      },
      {
        _id: 2,
        "image":"https://i.postimg.cc/ZmD3Xf57/Korean-style.jpg",
        "name":"Korean style",
        "date":"2022-08-12",
        "description":"Enjoy the best Korean dishes, with international chefs and awesome events.",
        "category":"Food Fair",
        "place":"Room A",
        "capacity":45000,
        "assistance":42756,
        "price":10
      },
      {
        _id: 3,
        "image":"https://i.postimg.cc/GmHRkbNV/Jurassic-Park.jpg",
        "name":"Jurassic Park",
        "date":"2021-11-02",
        "description":"Let's go meet the biggest dinosaurs in the paleontology museum.",
        "category":"Museum",
        "place":"Field",
        "capacity":82000,
        "assistance":65892,
        "price":15}
```

*estaba pensando hacerlo con un if y si cumple los datos imprima pero no me sale se la logica no el codigo :C:C
no puedo usar la fecha solo llamar a la date para que compare el current que tiene adentro*

Answer (score 0):

Podés saltear una iteración utilizando una condicional cuando el `currentDate` sea mayor al tiempo del evento, es decir, que ya ha sucedido:

```
function cargarTarjetas(eventsArray, container) {
  let cardsData = "";
  for (const event of eventsArray) {
    if (new Date(data.currentDate) > new Date(event.date)) continue;
    cardsData += `<div class="card">
        <img src="${event.image}" class="card-img-top" alt="${event.name}">
            <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
                <div class="row">
                    <h5 class="card-title">${event.name}</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="row flex-grow-1">
                    <div class="col">
                        <p class="card-text">${event.description}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex flex-nowrap align-content-center align-items-center">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1">
                        Price: $ ${event.price}
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex flex-grow-0">
                        <a href="./details.html" class="btn btn-primary">Details</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>`;
  }
  container.innerHTML = cardsData;
};
```

Como verás solo estoy agregando ese `if` que mencionabas, al inicio de cada iteración dentro del `for`. El `continue` salta la iteración si el evento actual es antes que el `currentDate`.